# C# WPF Display a Listview Control over a listview item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

Ok so I've been looking for a WPF listview that works something like a treeview.  I have a Data Model that has an observerableCollection of children of the item.  I've looked at a few options using a few treeview with columns controls that have been shown on stackoverflow or on CodeProject but they either aren't bindable or are too slow to be useful.

The list will be update constantly throughout the day any may have more than 50k-100k items in it by the end of the day.  A normal listview control seems to be able to handle these updates and still be useful without completely freezing when a resort is needed.

Now, my data objects should really only ever have one layer of children. So what I was thinking about trying is displaying a toggle button on the listview item (if the item has children), but then when the toggle button is clicked I want to display another listview of that item's children within the current listviewitem.  I've been searching for more than a week trying to figure out how to do this.  Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?  I'm thinking I need a ItemTemplate for the listview but I'm not exactly sure how to get the child listview to show in the parent's listviewitem.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Here is a sample of the XAML I'm currently trying to use but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  I want the columns but when I click the toggle button I want the sub listview to be displayed.  Currently all I see is the columns and I can't get the sub listview to display.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="lsvMyList">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                         <ListView.View>
                              <GridView>
                                   <GridViewColumn Header="Column2"
                                                   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}"
                                                   Width="100"/>
                                     <GridViewColumn Header="Column3"
                                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}"
                                                     Width="100"/>
                                     <GridViewColumn Header="Column5"
                                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column5}"
                                                     Width="100"/>
                                     <GridViewColumn Header="Column8"
                                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column8}"/>
                                </GridView>
                           </ListView.View>
                      </ListView>
                 </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                 <GridViewColumn Width="68" Header="IsExpanded">
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                     <ToggleButton Visibility="{Binding ChildCount, Converter={StaticResource Toggle}}"
                                                   x:Name="tbnItemExpander"
                                                   Content="+"
                                                   Height="15"
                                                   Width="15"
                                                   BorderThickness="0"
                                                   Background="Transparent"
                                                   IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"   
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                   Click="Toggle_Click"/>

                                          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                     Text="{Binding ChildCount, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource RejectCount2}}"
                                                     Margin="2,0,2,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Column2"
                                 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Width="63"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Column3"
                                 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Width="28"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Column4"
                                 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Width="68"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header=""
                                 Width="110">
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                     <Button Click="Button_Click"
                                             Margin="2" Padding="2"
                                             IsEnabled="{Binding Column5, Converter={StaticResource IsNull}}"
                                             Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource btnContent}}"
                                             Tag="{Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                 </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                       </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn>
             </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
```

Comment: Put an inner ListBox (or ItemsControl if items do not need to be selectable) in the ItemTemplate of the outer ListBox or ListView, and bind its ItemsSource property to a collection property of the outer item class.

Comment: Can you provide a quick sample?